# Rails cache and user specific content

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

Lets say I have a next view:

```
<% cache ['v1', post] do %>
    <article class="post">
        <%= render post.author %>
        <%= post.body %>
    </article>
<% end %>
```

This will work fine, but how do I implement a caching in case I need to show Delete, Edit links for the Admin user - something like:

```
<% cache ['v1', post] do %>
    <article class="post">
        <%= render post.author %>
        <%= post.body %>
    </article>
    <% if @admin? %>
        <%# Content specific for Admin %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

The only idea I have is to add a parameter to the Caching Key - Simple User or Admin - then they will have a different caches. Is it a right way to go?

Comment: Yes, that would work. There is no "right" way in caching. It all depends on your business logic and application constraints.

Comment: I see, but the thing is that lets say I wanna show specific content for user which is logged in, then as far as I understand adding user_id to the cache key is not a good idea, is it? What way to go then?
I will update a question a bit

Comment: It is totally valid to use the approach of adding a `user_id` to the cache key. Like I said, it all depends on your application. How many users there are, how likely it is that there are cache-hits, how big the cache will grow etc. That is nothing that can be answered on SO.

Answer (score 1):

Add `current_user` to the cache call:

```
<% cache ['v1', current_user, post] do %>
    <article class="post">
        <%= render post.author %>
        <%= post.body %>
    </article>
    <% if @admin? %>
        <%# Content specific for Admin %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several possibilities. You can decide to skip the cache if the user is admin, or to append another parameter to the cache path.

This is the second solution.

```
<% cache ['v1', post, "admin:#{admin?}"] do %>
  <article class="post">
    <%= render post.author %>
    <%= post.body %>
  </article>
  <% if @admin? %>
    <%# Content specific for Admin %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

The first one may be very helpful if you have different level of admin, or to ensure that admin always access the most fresh content.

Another possibility is to not render the link directly in the cached helper, but just leave a placeholder. Then, using an async call in AJAX, append the links or (generally speaking) all the admin features.